# How to wrap external paths (include, lib) and definitions into a target in cmake

Tags: cmake, libraw

Rather than providing a target, some libraries like `LibRaw` generate variables that contain information about include paths, library paths and compile definitions. In the case of `LibRaw`, vcpkg recommends the following usage:

```
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE ${LibRaw_DEFINITIONS})
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${LibRaw_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${LibRaw_LIBRARIES})
```

However, I would much rather stay consistent on linking libraries using

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE LibRaw)
```

Is there a way to wrap all of the provided variables into a target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create your own [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) and define the properties that should be applied to the `main` target with `INTERFACE` visibility:

```
add_library(MyLibRaw INTERFACE)
target_compile_definitions(MyLibRaw INTERFACE ${LibRaw_DEFINITIONS})
target_include_directories(MyLibRaw INTERFACE ${LibRaw_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(MyLibRaw INTERFACE ${LibRaw_LIBRARIES})
```

This way every linking target linking `MyLibRaw` will inherit those properties.

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE MyLibRaw)
```

Note that if you're reusing the target across multiple projects, you may want to create a find script that provides this target, if you do `find_package(MyImports COMPONENTS LibRaw)` or similar...

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own target:

```
add_library( MyLibRaw INTERFACE IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(MyLibRaw 
    PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LibRaw_INCLUDE_DIR}
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG ${LibRaw_LIBRARIES_debug}
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE ${LibRaw_LIBRARIES_release}
        IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG ${LibRaw_LIBRARIES_shared_debug}
        IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${LibRaw_LIBRARIES_shared_release}
)

target_link_libraries(MyLibRaw 
    INTERFACE
        optimized $<TARGET_PROPERTY:MyLibRaw ,IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE>
        debug $<TARGET_PROPERTY:MyLibRaw ,IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG>
)
```